# Why other togglebuttons aren't working in my Onclick method?

Tags: android, onclick, togglebutton

```
              package com.uygulamalar.androidce;


              import android.app.Activity;
              import android.media.MediaPlayer;
              import android.os.Bundle;
              import android.view.View;
              import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
               import android.widget.ToggleButton;

    public class EglenceliSeslerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        ToggleButton togg1,togg2,togg3,togg4,togg5,togg6,togg7,togg8,togg9;
         MediaPlayer sincap,seytanikahkaha,bateri,kalpatisi,trololo,kedicanini,haha,alkis,dedeler;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            togg1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg1);
            togg2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg2);
            togg3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg3);
            togg4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg4);
            togg5 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg5);
            togg6 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg6);
            togg7 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg7);
            togg8 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg8);
            togg9 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg9);

            sincap = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dramatiksincap);
            seytanikahkaha = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.seytanikahkaha);
            bateri = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bateri);
            kalpatisi = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalpatisi);
            trololo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.trololo);
            kedicanini = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kedicanini);
            haha = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.haha);
            alkis = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alkis);
           dedeler = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dedeler);

           togg1.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg2.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg3.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg4.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg5.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg6.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg7.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg8.setOnClickListener(this);
           togg9.setOnClickListener(this);

       }
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.togg1:
        if(togg1.isChecked()) {
            sincap.start();
            sincap.setLooping(true);
        }
        else
            sincap.pause();


    case R.id.togg2:
        if(togg2.isChecked()) {
            seytanikahkaha.start();
            seytanikahkaha.setLooping(true);
        }
        else
            seytanikahkaha.pause();

    case R.id.togg3:
        if(togg3.isChecked()) {
            bateri.start();
            bateri.setLooping(true);
        }
        else
            bateri.pause();

    case R.id.togg4:
        if(togg4.isChecked()) {
            kalpatisi.start();
            kalpatisi.setLooping(true);
        }
        else
            kalpatisi.pause();

    case R.id.togg5:
        if(togg5.isChecked()) {
            trololo.start();
            trololo.setLooping(true);
        }
        else
            trololo.pause();

    case R.id.togg6:
        if(togg6.isChecked()) {
            kedicanini.start();
            kedicanini.setLooping(true);
        }
        else
            kedicanini.pause(); 
    }



  }




 }
```

Why the other toggle buttons not playing audios except than first one when i click on them? The first toggle button plays the audio sincap well but the others dom't play the audios. Can you tell me why? Thx.

Comment: I am sorry. Problem solved. Me dumb forgot to add break statements end of each case.

Answer (score 0):

After each `case` you should have a `break` statement so that you don't fall through to the next case. I.e.:

```
...

switch(v.getId()) {

case R.id.togg1:
    if(togg1.isChecked()) {
        sincap.start();
        sincap.setLooping(true);
    }
    else
        sincap.pause();

    break;
case R.id.togg2:
    if(togg2.isChecked()) {
        seytanikahkaha.start();
        seytanikahkaha.setLooping(true);
    }
    else
        seytanikahkaha.pause();
    break;

    ...
```